# JavaScript destructuring Objects

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following object (data model):

```
const TimeSheetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    duration: {
        start: Date,
        end: Date
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});
```

How do I destructure the `timeSheet` object in order to use field "start" in the sort function?

```
try {
    const timeSheets = await TimeSheet
        .find({isDeleted: false})
        .sort({start: -1});
    res.json(timeSheets);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
}
```

Comment: Please tag the relevant library in use next time, since normal js doesn't really work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using dot notation within quotes - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#examples

```
try {
    const timeSheets = await TimeSheet
        .find({isDeleted: false})
        .sort({"duration.start": -1});
    res.json(timeSheets);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
}
```